# Spring Boot OAuth With Okta Always Redirects to Login Page

Tags: oauth-2.0, okta, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to get Okta OAuth setup with my spring boot app. I can get it to redirect to the authorization page, but after authenticating with okta I always just get bumped back to the login page. It seems as if the auth data from okta isn't being properly stored in the application.

You can see the full app [here](https://github.com/WyattPearson/spring-oauth2-test). I've omitted the sensitive data like clientid/secret for my okta dev instance and the keystore stuff.

This is my security config:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth_login")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .loginPage("/oauth_login")
            .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegRepo)
            .authorizedClientService(clientService)
            .tokenEndpoint()
            .accessTokenResponseClient(tokenClient);
}
```